# how can i set an event on custom button in actionColumn of gridView in yii?

Tags: javascript, php, html, gridview, yii2

I have this gridview code in my yii project, I want to call a next view when user clicks "change" button, plz help me tackle this issue. I have searched but could not get a comprehensive solution.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'name',
        'address:ntext',
        'banner_a4',
        'added_by',
        // 'ts',


        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'template' => '{view} {update} {delete} {change}',
            'buttons' => [
                'change' => function ($url,$model,$key) {
                        return Html::a('Change', $url);
                },
            ],

        ],


    ],

]); ?>
```

Comment: and your question?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you don't know how to set URL , look at this .

```
'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
     'template' => '{view} {change}',
                'buttons' => [


        'change' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
             $options = ['target' => '_blank',];
             return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>', Url::to(['/your-controller/nextview','id'=>$model->id]), $options);
        },
```